# How to disable primary main site header and logo in wordpress (Astra Theme)

Tags: themes, headers

I have installed astra theme on my wordpress. How can i disable primary header ?
I used following code in child theme but still didn't work.

```
   add_action( 'wp', 'astra_remove_header' );

function astra_remove_header() {
    remove_action( 'astra_masthead', 'astra_masthead_primary_template' );
}
```

here is the screenshot, I want to delete upper logo:

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

With CSS you can disable this upper logo.

```
display: none;
```